# remove an overlay in map

Tags: android

I am showing current location using a red marker and some other set of location using a blue marker. After an operation, I have to remove some of the locations indicated using blue marker. Rest should be shown in the map itself. How will I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `mapOverlays.remove()` cannot be kept in my code due to some other reasons, I cleared the complete set of overlays using `mapOverlays.clear()` and added those overlays wish I require.

Answer (score 4):

You can use mapOverlays.remove(1) 1 is the position of overlay or you can use object where you can remove overlays.

Answer (score 0):

You should use yourMapOverlays.remove(the_index_of_Obstacle); . For this reason you should keep track of the object you specifically need to update later or remove. like adding itat last and access it using yourMapOverlays.size()-1